# OS X Mavericks (or Yosemite) on new VM in Vsphere?

Tags: mac-osx, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, mac, vsphere-client

Am I able to install OS X on a VM in VMware VSphere Client? I've already got ESXi 5.5 installed on my testing environment at home on my Dell PowerEdge server with 4 VMs running windows OS's accessing them via Vsphere Client from my laptop.﻿

Something similar to this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quky-WIFZG8

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is against OSX licensing.

Comment: @EEAA It's not against licensing to run it on Apple hardware...

Comment: The OP is running it on a Dell PE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at this a few weeks ago.  If memory serves it is a qualified yes.

Specifically, it *is* supported by VmWare.  However, according the OS X licensing agreement, you must be running vSphere ESXi on *Apple hardware*.

Also as an FYI, there's some secret sauce stuff in the OS X installer that will detect non-Apple hardware on install and terminate the install if you attempt that.

See support details here: http://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/guest-os/unix-and-others/mac-osx

See licensing details here: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1000131

Comment: Thank you for the extra info. I have always heard that it has to be on Apple hardware, but after watching some youtube videos on how to get it on a PC, I couldn't find any for my particular situation. 

Why does Apple have to make it so hard all the time??? :)

Comment: @GregArnold I can understand why Apple do it, OSX works well because it is only run on a small set of hardware, but granted it makes things so f*$(ng hard for us techies that don't want (or can't afford) Apple hardware for running OSX on.

Comment: You should understand that Apple is primarily a hardware company -- from their perspective OS X and OS X Server exist to encourage you to buy Mac computers (which is why they give OS X away and charge just $20 for Server). Allowing them to run on non-Apple hardware would completely defeat this purpose. I'd love to see Apple sell a generic-hardware-virtualizable-server license for, say, $1000 (which would completely make up for what they're not making on the hardware), but that's just not the way Apple thinks.